# How do write conditional statement in a single line? rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring

I am trying to say this

```
self.preferred_amount * object.each{|li|li.variant}.collect{|li|li.weight}
```

The only problem is that certain weights equal nil.

Being that the case, I would like to add that if they do equal nil, make them equal 0.

Is there any way to incorporate this logic in the same line?

Or is there a way I can make this statement even more refactored than it is?

Comment: can you explain what the "object.each" is doing?

Comment: It's a bug to multiply a scalar amount by an array.  Do you mean to be computing the sum of the weights?

Comment: @wayne, yes, but I later added that. Thanks so much

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change `li.weight` to `li.weight || 0`

`||` is the "short circuit or" operator.  If its left hand side is truthy (neither false nor nil), it returns the left hand side, otherwise it returns the right hand side.

There is a feature in MRI >= 1.8.7 that will let you make this terser.  Instead of:

```
each{|li|li.variant}
```

you can write

```
each(&:variant)
```

In versions of Ruby before 1.8.7, require the backports gem to get this feature.

Better than that, move all of the logic into object's class, e.g.

```
class Whatever
  def variant_weights
    each(&:variant).collect{ |li| li.weight || 0}
  end
end
```

and to use it:

```
self.preferred_amount * object.variant_weights
```

However, note that it is a bug to multiply a scalar amount by an array.  If you mean to sum the weights, then:

```
class Whatever
  def total_variant_weights
    each(&:variant).collect{ |li| li.weight || 0}.inject(&:+)
  end
end
```

and to use it:

```
self.preferred_amount * object.total_variant_weights
```

Answer (score 5):

Note, all the answers above are **correct** for your purpose, but to answer your question directly:

> How do I write a conditional statement in a single line? Rails

You can use ternary operators. They take the following form:

```
assertion ? value_if_true : value_if_false
# if assertion is true, then value_if_true, otherwise, value_if_false
```

for example:

```
puts 4 < 5 ? 'you are on Earth' : 'you are on another planet'
<%= @user.is_admin? ? 'you can access this page' : 'you aren\'t allowed to be here' %>
```

Like I said, the answers above are actually what you want for this particular operation (not that a ternary operator *won't* work in this case). I just wanted to give you some more insight into one-liners.

Also note, this is not Ruby-specific. Most programming languages (including Ruby, PHP, CF, AS, JAVA, C, C#...) have ternary operators.

Comment: good answer, i have something like this @models = Model.find(:all).collect{|m| (modellist[m.id] > 0)? m:false  }, like this im forced to provide an alternative value (or else i get an error), is there a way to either make it have a value (on the left) or do nothing

Answer (score 2):

just `|| 0` the weight:

```
self.preferred_amount * object.each{|li|li.variant}.collect{|li|li.weight || 0}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
 .collect{|li|li.weight || 0}
```

Answer (score 2):

The each seems redundant. What about:

```
self.preferred_amount * object.collect { |o| o.variant.weight.to_i }
```

or if you really meant to sum the weights:

`self.preferred_amount * object.inject { |sum, o| sum + o.variant.weight.to_i }`